# How to create custom Facade in Laravel 4

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, facade

Looked up a few tutorials on facades and laravel 4... tried some... not liked the way they work.

For instance, they don't all provide a way of defining where to store the facade files and service providers... and i tried to step away from that and got my head bumped into a few walls until i decided to do this thread.

So: Let's say i have an app called Laracms (laravel cms).

I'd like to store everything i create - facades, service providers, etc in a folder under app named laracms.

So i'd have /app/laracms/facades, /app/laracms/serviceproviders and so on. I don't want to mix the facades with the database models, i want to keep things as separate as possible.

Let's take now, in my case, the Settings name for the facade (i want to implement a settings class to use in views and admin to set up misc. stuff).

Settings::get(), Settings::set() as methods.

Can anyone explain how to set facades up correctly? I don't know what i'm doing wrong and i need a fresh start.

Thanks,
Chris

Looking for a step by step with simple explanations of how and why.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to go to `app/config/app.php` and in `providers` section add:

```
'Laracms\Providers\SettingsServiceProvider',
```

In the same file in `aliases` section you should add:

```
 'Settings' => 'Laracms\Facades\Settings',
```

In your `app/Laracms/Providers` you should create file `SettingsServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace Laracms\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SettingsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('settings', function()
            {
                return new \Laracms\Settings();
            });
    }

}
```

In your `app/Laracms/Facades/` you should create file `Settings.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Laracms\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Settings extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'settings'; }

}
```

Now in your `app/Laracms` directory you should create file `Settings.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Laracms;

class Settings {
   public function get() {echo "get"; }

   public function set() {echo "set"; }
}
```

As you wanted to have your files in custom folder `Laracms` you need to add this folder to your `composer.json` (If you used standard `app/models` folder you wouldn't need to add anything to this file). So now open `composer.json` file and in section `autoload` -> `classmap` you should add `app/Laracms` so this section of composer.json could look like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/Laracms"
    ]
},
```

Now you need to run in your console inside your project foler:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to create class map

If everything is fine, you should now be able to use in your applications `Settings::get()` and `Settings:set()`

You need to notice that I used folders with uppercases because namespaces by convention starts with upper letters.

Comment: Shouldn't i add the folders to the composer.json to autoload also? i am getting a SettingsServiceProvider class not found error

Comment: @ied3vil You were right, I've updated my post - you need to add your folder to `classmap` in `composer.json`

Comment: I figured out that initially, i now have a different question: The above code works fine now, but for instance i have, in the get() method i am trying to access DB:: facade... that is not working - any idea how i can make it work, the correct way?

Comment: @ied3vilb Please create new question with your code and DB structure if needed

Comment: I solved it - All i had to do was add a use statement inside the facade's class

Answer (score 2):

There are three components to making a Facade:

- The wanna be Facade Class, that class that needs to become a facade.
- The Facade required Class, which tells Laravel which registered class it pertains to
- A Service Provider, which registers the Facade class in the App container

**1. the wanna be Facade Class:**

```
<?php namespace Moubarmij\Services\ModelsServices;

class AuthenticationService extends MoubarmijService implements AuthenticationServiceInterface{


    /**
     * @param $email
     * @param $password
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function login($email, $password)
    {
        return Sentry::authenticate([
            'email'    => $email,
            'password' => $password,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        return Sentry::logout();
    }

}
```

**2. the required class for the facade to work:**

```
<?php namespace Moubarmij\Facades;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

/**
 * Class AuthenticationServiceFacade
 * @package Moubarmij\Services\ModelsServices
 */
class AuthenticationServiceFacade extends Facade{

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'authentication_service'; }


}
```

note: authentication_service can be anything you want (its the name of the component registered in the IOC)

**3. the service provider**

```
<?php namespace Moubarmij\Providers;


use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

/**
 *  A service provider for the Authentication Service
 *
 * Class AuthenticationServiceSP
 * @package Moubarmij\Providers
 */
class AuthenticationServiceSP extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * bind interfaces
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // Register 'authentication_service' instance container to our AuthenticationService object
        $this->app['authentication_service'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return $app->make('Moubarmij\Services\ModelsServices\AuthenticationService');
        });

        // Shortcut to auto add the Alias in app/config/app.php
        $this->app->booting(function()
        {
            $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
            $loader->alias('AuthenticationService', 'Moubarmij\Facades\AuthenticationServiceFacade');
        });

    }
}
```