# Laravel - Call to undefined method TrainingFacade::save()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, namespaces, inversion-of-control

I'm building a Laravel 4.2 app and I'm using Creolab's Modules package. It's an app for managing company trainings, so my module is called Trainings. All works well except saving newly created trainings. The error I receive when I submit the Create New form is:

```
Call to undefined method Roche\Trainings\Facades\TrainingFacade::save()
```

[image]

These are my [TrainingsController](http://laravel.io/bin/roGae), [Training Model](http://laravel.io/bin/9vDL9), [TrainingFacade](http://laravel.io/bin/DekvW), [Trainings Service Provider](http://laravel.io/bin/PXrM9) and [routes](http://laravel.io/bin/42KzD). Nothing I try seems to fix it.

Comment: well you have given no info. Please paste your code here and paste the part that errors; give us the code where the request bumps into error.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here with a facade? You would want to be calling eloquents `save()` method on a record that you have modified. Also, I believe `getFacadeAccessor()` should return the class name as a string, not an instance.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi can you please tell me what more info you need? I provided my Controller, Model, Facade, Service provider and routes. The `if($this->training->save())` line in the Controller's postCreate method returns the error.

Comment: @Supericy I'm just trying to save the data from the form in the database. I don't think I understand what record am I modifying when I'm creating a new training. About the `getFacadeAccessor()` I only used the code shown in this example here: https://github.com/bstrahija/laravel-modules-example/blob/master/app/modules/content/facades/EntryFacade.php

Comment: But why do you need a custom Facade for that? Using the Model class directly should be perfectly fine.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I'm aware of that, and it actually works if I add `use \Namespace\Models\Training` to my controller. But I would still want to know why this code doesn't work. What's wrong in the current configuration?

Comment: I suppose something with having an alias the same name as a model is the problem. If you rename your alias, does it work?

Comment: Then I'm getting this error: `Class Training does not exist`.

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ I mean rename the alias where you use it as well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to change your facade alias here, but you have other error here.

In your `AdminTrainingsController` you want to use `Training` model so you import `Training` before your class definition this way:

```
use Training;
```

but model `Training` is not in root namespace, in root namespace there is `TrainingFacade` because you probably define it in your `app.php` file this way:

```
'Training' => 'Roche\Trainings\Facades\TrainingFacade',
```

That's ok, you don't need to change this facade alias.

So now, Laravel inject into your constructor not `Training` model but `TrainingFacade`  (because `Training` in root namespace is alias for `TrainingFacade`).

What you need here is importing correct namespace for your `Training` model.

When we look at your `Training` model class we see the code is:

```
<?php namespace Roche\Trainings\Models;

class Training extends \Eloquent {

protected $guarded = array('id');

}
```

so it's in `Roche\Trainings\Models` namespace.

So to make it work in `AdminTrainingsController` you need to change:

```
use Training;
```

into:

```
use Roche\Trainings\Models\Training;
```

Now Laravel will inject into constructor `Training` model (and not `TrainingFacade` as it was doing).

**EDIT**

You could also make some tests, for example changing in your `app.php` your `TrainingFacade` alias, for example to:

```
    'TrainingFacade' => 'Roche\Trainings\Facades\TrainingFacade',
```

but if you had `use Training` as you had, you would get the following error:

> Class Training does not exist

because there would be no `Training` class in global namespace now (you changed alias for facade).

And if you removed `use Training;` completely, you would get:

> Class Roche\Trainings\Controllers\Admin\Training does not exist

because by default class is loaded from current namespace, and your `AdminTrainingsController` is in `Roche\Trainings\Controllers\Admin` namespace

I hope now everything is clear, if it's not you could also look at [How to use objects from other namespaces and how to import namespaces in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607045/how-to-use-objects-from-other-namespaces-and-how-to-import-namespaces-in-php) where I explained more about namespaces

Comment: Marcin thank you very much for the thorough explanation. I now have two questions: 1. Why am I only getting this error when creating a new training, and not when I am updating an existing one? The code in both methods is almost the same. 2. Can you please look at my `TrainingFacade` and tell me if the code there is OK? @Supericy mentioned that a facade should return a string and not an instance. Is that correct, or is my code ok? Thanks.

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ And where do you have update method here? I see only create method

Comment: Sorry, I removed it to make my question more focused on this method only. This is actually my entire controller: http://laravel.io/bin/eDG9k . I would appreciate if you let me know if you see anything unusual.

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ This is different situation, because for other actions you use route model binding in routes. You have there `Route::model('training', 'Roche\Trainings\Models\Training');` - as you see also with full namespace. And about facades - yes, you return string here, you could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978931/how-to-create-custom-facade-in-laravel-4/25979624

Comment: Aaah, I get it now! This was really confusing me. Only now I realize why only `postCreate()` wasn't working. Marcin you're a star! Thank you so much for having so much patience. My problem here is, beside I'm a beginner, I'm combining https://github.com/bstrahija/laravel-modules-example and https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site, and the differences confuse me. Your links will help me a lot. Thanks again buddy!

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ Glad I could help, I'm also Laravel beginner :)