# Using Settings::get('var_name') in Laravel template instead of Config::get('file.var')

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to store my application settings in database. 
In order to get a variable in template, I'm currently using

`{{ Config::get('file.variable) }}` 
and settings are stored in config/file

I would like to create controller SettingsController with public static get and set methods and get variables in template in this way:

```
{{ Settings::get('var_name') }}
```

instead of

```
{{ SettingsController::get('var_name') }}
```

But I'm getting error: Class 'Settings' not found.

I've tried to set routes:

```
Route::controller('Settings', 'SettingsController'); and
Route::resource('Settings', 'SettingsController');
```

But none of the methods works. 
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: well, i don't think you need to define controller, just create a model with setting, map it according to your requirement and call it where ever you want to call.

Comment: and also take a look to package: https://github.com/anlutro/laravel-settings.

Comment: It would be called Setting then, I thought if it can be done using controller instead of model

Answer (score 0):

This should be done using facades, which is already answered here:

[How to create custom Facade in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978931/how-to-create-custom-facade-in-laravel-4)